# Level shifter circuit for bipolar battery

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, level-shifting, voltage-reference

I am using a 9 V bipolar battery and I want to have an output of 1.6 V for the ADC.

What would a level shifter circuit look like for that? Do you have a better suggestion I could look into?

Comment: For measuring the battery voltage with the ADC or as a reference voltage for the ADC?

Comment: as the reference to the ADC

Comment: Is that bipolar battery using lithium? :-)

Comment: @winny: Heehee. You made me spill some coffee there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a voltage reference, not a level shifter.

There are many ways of making a voltage reference, but the easiest and usually the most stable and precise is using a dedicated voltage reference IC.

1.6 V is a rare value though; I would use an adjustable one, like the [LMx85-ADJ](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm385-adj.pdf), but that is mainly because I have some of those lying around; there are many others. A Google search will turn up a great many (and many more for 1.5 V than for 1.6 V).

You will have to do some math to calculate the resistors needed to run it off 9 V and to set the voltage you want, but the datasheets will show you how that's done.