# 1.6v voltage reference with an input of 9 volt

Tags: voltage-reference

I am trying to find a voltage reference with an input of 9 volts. I was able to find two from maxim integrated but had a max input of 5v. I was trying to find a fixed 1.6 output but I wasn't able to find any. I am wondering if there is something specific I need to look for.

Comment: Maxim are the only folk that I know of that make 1.6 volt fixed references and they are all limited to an input supply of 6 volts maximum.

Comment: See my answer to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/531415/level-shifter-circuit-for-bipolar-battery/